# no permission to run -rwxrwxrwx 1 tux tux 19 Jan 23 12:46 idea_tmp_check.sh file

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, 15.10, intellij

I try to get IntelliJ running.
It complains that it can't run idea_tmp_check.sh file.

I changed the permissions to 777

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tux tux 19 Jan 23 12:46 idea_tmp_check.sh
```

Trying to run it from bash it is not displayed if I press Tab and it complains, that I don't have permissions to run the file.

```
sudo: unable to execute ./idea_tmp_check.sh: Permission denied
```

Ubuntu 15.10

fstab:

```
LABEL=linux /home ext4 rw,auto,user 0 1
```

Comment: You also need to check the directory you stored the file in. That has to have executable permissions too. And 777 is -never- the correct solution. Only the 1st digit needs to be 7. The 2nd can be 7 but the 3rd ... no. And 750 is more than enough.

Comment: parent directory drwxrwxr-x 2 tux tux 4096 Jan 23 12:46 tmp.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be because of the settings in fstab.

I had no `exec`-permissions set in the configuration

Changing

```
LABEL=linux /home ext4 rw,auto,user 0 1
```

to

```
LABEL=linux /home ext4 rw,auto,user,exec 0 1
```

solved it.